# Android: GridView in Viewpager - incorrect data is shown when swiping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm really hoping someone can help me with this problem. I've been struggling with it for a while now.

I have an android project that makes use of a navigation drawer as a menu which swaps out fragments. In the one fragment, I am making use of a tablayout and a viewpager, which has one fragment (as it uses the same data and layout), but just sorts the data differently based on which tab you're on. The data is in a gridview.

The problem that I am facing, is that the viewpager is showing the wrong data at the wrong index. For example, in the first tab, it shows the second tab's data. The second and third tab is fine, but if you scroll all the way to the third tab and back to the first tab, then the first tab is correct.

Another issue, if I swipe to the second tab, and scroll down in the grid view and then back up, it also changes the data for some weird reason.

I have tried many ways and also researched here for solutions and implemented it the way that it's supposed to be done, but I just can't get it to work properly. I am not sure what I am missing or where I am going wrong. Your help would be much appreciated.

**Here is my code:**

ContactsTabHolderFragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,container,false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_pager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_tab);

        contactsPagerAdapter = new ContactsPagerAdapter(getContext(),getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(contactsPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(contactsPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

        return rootView;
    }
```

ContactsTabFragment:

```
public static ContactsTabFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        ContactsTabFragment fragment = new ContactsTabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ContactsTabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
        Log.i("FRAGMENT " + mParam1 + " CREATED","here");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_all, container, false);

        grid = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_grid);
        contactsManager = new ContactsManager(grid,getContext());
        contactsManager.displayContactTab(mParam1);

        return rootView;

    }
```

The ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ContactsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final String[] titles = new String[]{"Recent","Frequent","A-Z"};
private Context context;

    public ContactsPagerAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager manager){

        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){

        return ContactsTabFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){

        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
       return 3;

    }
```

And the ContactsManager Class:

```
public ContactsManager(GridView gridView, Context context){
        this.contactsGridView = gridView;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ContactsManager(){
    }

    public void displayContactTab(int contactTabPosition){
        switch (contactTabPosition){
            case 0: Collections.sort(contacts, ContactItem.contactDateComparator);
                break;
            case 1: Collections.sort(contacts,ContactItem.contactFrequencyComparator);
                break;
            case 2: Collections.sort(contacts,ContactItem.contactNameComparator);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        setUpContactGridAdapter();
    }

    public void setUpContactGridAdapter(){
        adapter = new ContactGridAdapter(context,contacts);
        contactsGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        BankingApplication.getInstance().addAdapter(adapter);
        contactsGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```